# How to add data to a JSON file

Tags: php

I would like to be able to add to a JSON file via a online portal using PHP.

I have attempted to do this with the code below, How ever I am not familiar with PHP so I can not get further.

```
<?php

//Get the data from the url
$name = $_GET['name'];
$email = $_GET['email'];

// read json file
$data = file_get_contents('example.json');

// decode json
$json_arr = json_decode($data, true);

// add data
$json_arr[] = array(4, 'Name'=>$name, 'email'=>$email);

// encode json and save to file
file_put_contents('example.json', json_encode($json_arr));
?>
```

My attempt:

`[{"0":4,"Name":"kieran","email":"ex@ex.com"}]`

What I would want to add

//This is want the JSON should be

```
 "0": {
    "conditionName": "u",
    "ignoreFollowing": false,
    "emailsThisSession": 0,
    "recieverEmails": [
      "example@g.c"
    ],
    "alertType": 1,
    "emailProperty": 2,
    "triggers": {
      "0": {
        "Property": 2,
        "Value": "zk-reg",
        "ComparisonType": "Equals"
      }
    }
  },
```

This is the whole JSON:

```
{
  "0": {
    "conditionName": "u",
    "ignoreFollowing": false,
    "emailsThisSession": 0,
    "recieverEmails": [
      "example@g.c"
    ],
    "alertType": 1,
    "emailProperty": 2,
    "triggers": {
      "0": {
        "Property": 2,
        "Value": "zk-reg",
        "ComparisonType": "Equals"
      }
    }
  },
  "1": {
    "conditionName": "k",
    "ignoreFollowing": false,
    "emailsThisSession": 0,
    "recieverEmails": [
      "h@f.com"
    ],
    "alertType": 1,
    "emailProperty": 0,
    "triggers": {
      "0": {
        "Property": 0,
        "Value": "",
        "ComparisonType": "Equals"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. What's the problem with the code you have?

Comment: In the PHP I am not sure how to insert all the data in that format.

Comment: Have edited post.

Comment: You add data to a php array with array_push($array, $value1, $value2); I think what you are doing is setting the array equal to array(4, 'Name'=>$name, 'email'=>$email); after decoding it. rather decoding the json and then using array_push to add to that current array.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly you want to do something like

```
<?php



 // read json file in this case I just include it in the script for simplicity

$data = '{
  "0": {
    "conditionName": "u",
    "ignoreFollowing": false,
    "emailsThisSession": 0,
    "recieverEmails": [
      "example@g.c"
    ],
    "alertType": 1,
    "emailProperty": 2,
    "triggers": {
      "0": {
        "Property": 2,
        "Value": "zk-reg",
        "ComparisonType": "Equals"
      }
    }
  },
  "1": {
    "conditionName": "k",
    "ignoreFollowing": false,
    "emailsThisSession": 0,
    "recieverEmails": [
      "h@f.com"
    ],
    "alertType": 1,
    "emailProperty": 0,
    "triggers": {
      "0": {
        "Property": 0,
        "Value": "",
        "ComparisonType": "Equals"
      }
    }
  }
}';

// decode json
$json_arr = json_decode($data, true);
echo "Before Count " . count($json_arr);
// add data
//put the array of variables you want to add into its own var, add each variable you want, I've done the first two
$rowToAdd = array("conditionName" => "y",  "ignoreFollowing" => false, "emailsThisSession" => 800, "recieverEmails" => array("h@f.com"));

//use array_push to add to the current array rather over-writing it 
array_push($json_arr , $rowToAdd);
echo "After Count " . count($json_arr);
// encode json and save to file
file_put_contents('example.json', json_encode($json_arr));
?>
```

Comment: I am wanting to get all the data from a form then add it to the JSON in this format:  `"0": {
    "conditionName": "u",
    "ignoreFollowing": false,
    "emailsThisSession": 0,
    "recieverEmails": [
      "example@g.c"
    ],
    "alertType": 1,
    "emailProperty": 2,
    "triggers": {
      "0": {
        "Property": 2,
        "Value": "zk-reg",
        "ComparisonType": "Equals"
      }
    }
  },`

Comment: I see give me a few minutes, I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Pheonix2105 Apologies for not making very clear.

Comment: take a look at http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3n6u-hgh1 make sure to press f9 to run it, is this what you want? You will notice I do a var dump instead of writing to json file since you obviously cant in phpfiddle but you can just fine in your script.

@radar

Comment: Yup thanks that will get me started will add the rest of the vars in.

Comment: @Phoenix2105, When I run the code the JSON turns into this: `[{"conditionName":"u","ignoreFollowing":false,"emailsThisSession":0,"recieverEmails":["example@g.c"],"alertType":1,"emailProperty":2,"triggers":[{"Property":2,"Value":"zk-reg","ComparisonType":"Equals"}]},
{"conditionName":"k","ignoreFollowing":false,"emailsThisSession":0,"recieverEmails":["h@f.com"],"alertType":1,"emailProperty":0,"triggers":[{"Property":0,"Value":"","ComparisonType":"Equals"}]},
{"conditionName":"y","ignoreFollowing":false,"emailsThisSession":800,"recieverEmails":["h@f.com"]}]`

Comment: Instead of original template

Comment: update your question with your current code please with all the variables implemented as it seems it's only adding the ones I included in the example.

Comment: please check updated version have added //This is want the JSON should be the the format.

Comment: `0
conditionName
ignoreFollowing
emailsThisSession
recieverEmails[]
alertType
emailProperty
triggers  {
      "0": {
        Property
        Value
        ComparisonType
      }
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
//$data is data you wanto add.
$json_files = file_get_contents('example.json');
$tempArray = json_decode($json_files);
array_push($tempArray, $data);
$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
file_put_contents('example.json', $jsonData);
```